# Using View::share in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use View::share to pass data to all my views. All I do is like this on my AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
    {
        $stok = Produk::where('jumlah_stok', 0);
        View::share('stok', $stok);
    }
```

and when I'm trying to checking it on my view. it shows error like this `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\sippo\resources\views\master.blade.php)`

```
<ul class="nav">
                    @if(Auth::user()->admin==0)
                        <li><a href="/"><i class="lnr lnr-home"></i><span>Dashboard{{$stok}}</span></a></li>
```

Am I wrong or there is something else I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this.

***Number one:***

by doing this: `Produk::where('jumlah_stok', 0)` you're getting a query builder object. I assume you want one single record, so you should do: `Produk::where('jumlah_stok', 0)->first()`

---

***Number two:***

When you try to use your variable in your view, you use double brackets (`{{$stok}}`). Laravel will sanitize this input, and try to force it through `htmlspecialchars()`, which won't work, because `htmlspecialchars()` expects a string, and right now, you're feeding it a query builder object. If you wish to use unsanitized variables in your views, use this syntax: `{!! $stok !!}`.

---

***Number three:***

Even if you were to update both of the previous things, you'd most likely still not end up with the wanted result, since you'll echo a collection to a view. Now, I don't know the structure of your database table, but let's say the `Product` table has a row called `name`, you'd have to do the following in your view: `{{ $stok->name }}` (*`{!! $stok->name !!}` would also work, but it'd be unsanitized).

Hope this helped. Cheers!